# Modal popup php, bootstrap

Tags: modalpopup

I have 10 products in product gallery page. if I click on view more button of a product. I need to display its product details in popup.

Code:

```
<li data-dialogModalBind="#product-1" class="product">
<?php echo '<img src="" />';?>
<h4><?php echo $name?></h4>      
<span>View More</span>
```

**In POPup section(In same page)**

```
<div id="product-1" class="dialog_content" style="display:none">
<div class="dialogModal_header">Product Details</div>
```

Comment: Did you try at least adding a link to product details?

Comment: I want <li> not <a href>.When I click view more pop window will display..But need to integrate the product name  and details there.

Comment: So what is your problem actually? creating a popup? or creating a list?

Comment: when I click on view more button of a product,a modal pop up will come..but how to display the product details inside that pop up(ie,its product name,image,decription)

Comment: So I think your question is about populating data in popup window. Right? In that case you may use `ajax` for fetching data. You may get some hint here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm